# Django admin "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" Key (user_id)=(1) already exists

Tags: django, postgresql

This is only happening to me when I try to update anything via the django admin site. Otherwise I have no problems. The error I am getting is:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/ledger/user/1/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ledger_googleprofile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
```

Here is what my google profile model looks like:

```
#ledger.models
class GoogleProfile(models.Model):
    plus_id = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    info = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    youtube_info = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='google_profile', blank=True, null=True)
```

I've tried running `python manage.py sqlsequencereset ledger` and then pasting that into psql, but that isn't solving the problem. It's weird because even users that don't have a GoogleProfile associated with them still throw this error when trying to save in the admin.

Any ideas on what the problem could be. I would rather not have to delete my production database and start over...

After writing this out I think the problem might be because the `GoogleProfile.user` field may have been a `oneToOne` before. I am not positive but I think it was a oneToOne that I changed to a ForeignKey (many to one) which would explain why there are problems with a unique constraint. But should running `manage.py makemigrations and migrate` solve the problem? Any idea how to solve this manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the constraint manually, run the following to double check the constraint name:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.constraint_table_usage
WHERE table_name = 'ledger_googleprofile';
```

Then

```
ALTER TABLE ledger_googleprofile DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Given the error you've posted I'd guess the actual SQL is that below, but I'd run the SELECT query just to double check:

```
ALTER TABLE ledger_googleprofile DROP CONSTRAINT ledger_googleprofile_user_id_key;
```

Comment: I figured out that I needed to just remove the constraint, but I couldn't figure out how to get the name of the constraint. You were right, it was istting in front of me the whole time 'ledger_googleprofile_user_id_key'. Thanks.

Comment: Had been struggling to fix this. Thank you.