# Loading data from Json file into PostgresSql causes: ERROR "duplicate key value violates unique constraint - already exists."

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I am deploying my Django site on to Google Cloud. One of the step is to change the database to postgresSQL. As I am using SqlLite locally I wanted to migrate all of the database into postgresSql. I followed an online guide where you Dump your data first and then change Database in settings.py to your new database. I have done everything upto this command;

```
    python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
```

where datadump.json is the dumped database from SQLITE. Now I am stuck with this error

```
      django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtur, Could not 
    load users.Profile(pk=3): duplicate key value violates unique 
    constraint "users_profile_user_id_key" DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
```

and I don't have any idea as to what to do. Some answers I looked up such as this:

[postgresql duplicate key violates unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448340/postgresql-duplicate-key-violates-unique-constraint)

AND

[Django admin "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" Key (user_id)=(1) already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759734/django-admin-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-key-user-id-1)

haven't helped, as I cannot understand what's going on. I did use MySQL 6 years ago, but I cannot understand this.

I managed to run some SQL commands from online resources and managed to produce this for my database:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb9ns.jpg

I followed these guides:

https://medium.com/@aaditya.chhabra/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-272d59d28fa5

https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/django-transfer-data-from-sqlite-to-another-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Drop the database
2. create a new one and run migrations

   python manage.py migrate

And try importing data from json file using,

```
python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
```

The errors are caused by the superuser object in the database you created using 'createsuperuser' command.

Comment: I tried to do that, still gave the same error. and I don't have any superusers as is obvious. 
Here's the error;
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\Users\~\myDjangoSite\venv\my
Site\datadump.json': Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=1): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_c
ontent_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (app_label, model)=(admin, logentry) already exists.

Comment: Here's the log from 
>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions, users
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Just delete the unwanted record from `django_site` table.

---

**Brief**

I had the same problem because I used **Signin with Google** in my site. So I tried it 2 times to see how to setup **Social Login**. As a result, table `django_site` created 2 records. Just delete the unwanted record from that *Table* or *Collection*

Comment: Hi, How to do it?
I mean How do I know there is unwanted record in Table?

Comment: If you have only used *Signin with Google*. Open your database. Now, open table named `django_site`. If there are more than 1 record, that record is the unwanted record. In my case, `id:1` was unwanted. If you have used multiple authentication like facebook and google both. Sorry, I cant help you.